# Reuse same Identity in MVC app as authenticated by Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

We are trying to take user login thru an MVC app (not redirect), but have primary authentication done through a Web API 2.0 endpoint, but *also* be able to authenticate user access to pages from that point on. Naturally we would track the token needed to authenticate future API calls.

However, there is no established User.Identity in the MVC app since we are doing this externally, and we need this User.Identity to enforce authentication for the MVC pages themselves (on a level before it reaches the controller).

So how can I adopt or impersonate the user?

I would've thought the general area of external auth would be it, but when I look at the diagrams showing how it would work, both seem to involve the user's machine directly interacting with the authenticating server (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services). We want the API to be inaccessible by the user's machine, except through the web app, so redirects of requests TO the API are not acceptable.